# Must I return something in my view function after an ajax Get request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

I'm doing a simple ajax call to my Flask application like this:

```
$("#add").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           url: '{{ url_for("ajax_add",  product_id=product.id ) }}
});
```

If I return nothing in my view function I get `ValueError: View function did not return a response`. If I instead do

```
return jsonify(result={})
```

then I get a success. Why is this necessary? What is the correct way to handle this?

Comment: Flask requires you to return a response-like object. It can be as simple as a string like `'ok'`.

Answer (score -1):

type: 'POST' should not require any return values.

GET is supposed to retrieve data.

Comment: OK. But even if I change the request to POST, why does my ajax call need to get anything back? Why is `return jsonify(res={})` better than just `return`?

Comment: Just my guess:

Usually you want something back, even if its just to tell it was a success or not.

jsonify actually creates something and returns a value, even if its an "empty" one.